# cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Tags: linq, wcf, entity-framework, error-handling, implicit-conversion

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to use entity framework to provide data to a WCF service. The code follows:

```
public IQueryable<vwTP90Web> GetTP90()
    {
            TP90Entities context = new TP90Entities();
            var tp90web = (from p
                          in context.vw_TP90Web
                          select p).Cast<IQueryable<vwTP90Web>>();
            return tp90web;

    }
```

it works fine until I try to return the data and then I get the message:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type        
'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IQueryable<TP90Service.vwTP90Web>>' to 
'System.Linq.IQueryable<TP90Service.vwTP90Web>'. An explicit conversion exists (are   
 you missing a cast?)
```

I've been chasing this for days and I just can't wrap my head around what it's looking for. I had the service running when I returned one item,but for the project I need to return a list. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the `IQueryable<T>` in your cast:

```
       var tp90web = (from p
                      in context.vw_TP90Web
                      select p).Cast<vwTP90Web>();
```

Note that this will still fail at runtime if the query is not returning `vwTP90Web` instances.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this should work fine*

```
public IEnumerable<vwTP90Web> GetTP90()
{
    var context = new TP90Entities();
    return (from p
           in context.vw_TP90Web
           select Convert(p)).ToArray();
}

private TP90Service.vwTP90Web Convert(P90MVC.DomainEntity.Models.vw_TP90Web source)
{
    vwTP90Web result = null;
    // I don't know how to convert vw_TP90Web types to vwTP90Web types
    // Nobody here can do this for you
    // So you will have to fill in the code here.
    return result;
}
```

There are a couple things going on here you have to understand.

First, the `Cast<T>()` method *casts every element within the enumerable to T*, it does *NOT* cast the enumerable instance to a different type.

Second, Linq methods are not executed immediately, they are executed when you trip the enumerable.  That means, by the time you start enumerating the result of this method, `TP90Entities` has gone out of scope and the method will fail.  And that any other errors in the method won't crop up until you enumerate.  So I am calling `ToArray()` in order to force execution of the query.

<sup>* Assuming you know how to convert `vw_TP90Web` to `vwTP90Web`</sup>

Comment: ToList() is also widely used, but you got the point and the +1

Comment: @MareInfinitus: I usually go with the array because its performant.  At least I believe it is.  I also believe that "performant" is a word.

Comment: I'm still getting error messages with both of the suggested answers. the message follows.  Cannot implicitly convert type 'TP90MVC.DomainEntity.Models.vw_TP90Web[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TP90Service.vwTP90Web>'  and yes vwTP90Web is a collection of columns described in my interface.

Comment: have no studio here right now to try it myself, but a `select new` should solve the problem (create the instances you need)

Comment: @Mykal73: You have to know that you are trying to convert one type to another.  That's pretty basic stuff, and something you need to know how it works to get to this point.  As nobody knows what is in these two different types, we can't tell you how to map back and forth between the two.  If you can't figure that out, you probably need to back off, do some reading, or talk to some of your co-workers.